# c++ enum class integer not working for array subscript

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following enum class:

```
enum class EnumClass : int
{
    A = 0, B
};
```

Now I want to subscript with that enum type to an array:

```
MyObject arr[2];
.
.
.
MyObject a = arr[EnumClass::A]
MyObject b = arr[EnumClass::B]
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
array subscript is not an integer
```

As enum classes are strongly typed I would expect this to work.

Comment: strongly typed enums cannot be implicitly converted to `int`. Use a regular `enum` or `static_cast`

Comment: Implicit casts aren't allowed with scoped enums. You can still do a `static_cast`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> As enum classes are strongly typed I would expect this to work

On the contrary, that's exactly why it won't work. Scoped enumerations will not implicitly convert to the underlying type. Use `static_cast` instead.

```
MyObject a = arr[static_cast<int>(EnumClass::A)];
```